# neural networks - removing noise from .wav files

Tags: matlab, neural-network

Is there any way how to remove noise from audio files - with neural networks? I want to remove noise from speech, for example in Matlab. Thank you.

Comment: This question is far too broad.  The trivial answer is "probably yes".  I suggest you look for a review paper on the subject (or ask your supervisor/professor to suggest some reading).

Comment: What is noise?  It is a simple question to ask, but is the crux of measurement.  The question is amazingly broad.  If you are looking for the sound of quantum mechanical phenomena then human voices are noise.  If you are looking for the sound of human voices then some sort of quantum phenomena (cosmic rays?) is noise.  These are mutually exclusive definitions.  Why not make a "sandbox" problem that is the simplest still-meaningful test case where you can engage this and make meaningful learning?  You could modify the question in that way.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you clean out noise (doesn't answer the neural networks question).

"Create and Implement LMS Adaptive Filter to remove the filtered noise from desired signal"

sauce: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/106510

```
mtlb_noisy = y;
noise = n;
% Define Adaptive Filter Parameters
filterLength = 32;
weights = zeros(1,filterLength);
step_size = 0.004;
% Initialize Filter's Operational inputs
output = zeros(1,length(mtlb_noisy));
err = zeros(1,length(mtlb_noisy));
input = zeros(1,filterLength);
% For Loop to run through the data and filter out noise
for n = 1: length(mtlb_noisy),
      %Get input vector to filter
      for k= 1:filterLength
          if ((n-k)>0)
              input(k) = noise(n-k+1);
          end
      end
      output(n) = weights * input';  %Output of Adaptive Filter
      err(n)  = mtlb_noisy(n) - output(n); %Error Computation
      weights = weights + step_size * err(n) * input; %Weights Updating 
  end
yClean = err;
```